# Error: Member not found: 'strokeAlignInside'

Tags: android, flutter

Error: Member not found: 'strokeAlignInside'.

This is a college project submission that I am working on, a simple quiz app. This error outlines this part:

```
double get strokeAlignInside => BorderSide.strokeAlignInside;

double get strokeAlignCenter => BorderSide.strokeAlignCenter;

double get strokeAlignOutside => BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside;
```

When ran, Android Studio would pop with this error

```
lib/theme/app_decoration.dart:93:44: Error: Member not found: 'strokeAlignInside'.
double get strokeAlignInside => BorderSide.strokeAlignInside;
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/theme/app_decoration.dart:95:44: Error: Member not found: 'strokeAlignCenter'.
double get strokeAlignCenter => BorderSide.strokeAlignCenter;
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/theme/app_decoration.dart:97:45: Error: Member not found: 'strokeAlignOutside'.
double get strokeAlignOutside => BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside;
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Just in-case, the entire code block of the file contains:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_5/core/app_export.dart';


class AppDecoration {
  static BoxDecoration get fillTeal50 => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.teal50,
      );
  static BoxDecoration get blueish => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.indigo900,
      );
  static BoxDecoration get outlineBlack90099 => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.indigoA200,
      );
  static BoxDecoration get outlineRedA700 => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.red200,
        border: Border.all(
          color: ColorConstant.redA700,
          width: getHorizontalSize(
            5,
          ),
        ),
      );
  static BoxDecoration get fillIndigoA200 => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.indigoA200,
      );
  static BoxDecoration get outlineIndigoA700 => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.blue100,
        border: Border.all(
          color: ColorConstant.indigoA700,
          width: getHorizontalSize(
            5,
          ),
        ),
      );
  static BoxDecoration get fillBlueA70001 => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.blueA70001,
      );
  static BoxDecoration get white => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
      );
  static BoxDecoration get outlineBlack9003f => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.indigoA70075,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: ColorConstant.black9003f,
            spreadRadius: getHorizontalSize(
              2,
            ),
            blurRadius: getHorizontalSize(
              2,
            ),
            offset: Offset(
              0,
              4,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
  static BoxDecoration get txtOutlineBlack9003f => BoxDecoration();
  static BoxDecoration get splash => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.indigoA400,
      );
  static BoxDecoration get fillGray400 => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.gray400,
      );
  static BoxDecoration get outlineGreenA400 => BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorConstant.greenA100,
        border: Border.all(
          color: ColorConstant.greenA400,
          width: getHorizontalSize(
            5,
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class BorderRadiusStyle {
  static BorderRadius roundedBorder35 = BorderRadius.circular(
    getHorizontalSize(
      35,
    ),
  );
}

double get strokeAlignInside => BorderSide.strokeAlignInside;

double get strokeAlignCenter => BorderSide.strokeAlignCenter;

double get strokeAlignOutside => BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside;
```

I am using Flutter 3.3.10. Any work around would be helpful!

I tried looking up similar errors but there's not much references. The syntax seemed like proper from the documentation so I am really not sure what is the error.

Comment: Can you try using a different name for the getter. Like this `double get myFunc => BorderSide.strokeAlignCenter`

Comment: I just tried, but it didn't work either. It still gives out the same error as above.

Comment: how are you trying to access it? Can you show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
              side: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.blue,
                width: 5,
                strokeAlign: strokeAlignInside,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

double get strokeAlignInside => BorderSide.strokeAlignInside;

double get strokeAlignCenter => BorderSide.strokeAlignCenter;

double get strokeAlignOutside => BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside;
```